# Коллекция была изменена; невозможно выполнить операцию перечисления C#

Tags: c#

все не могу разобраться, где допустил ошибку. Принцип работы функций прост, в глобальный переменных List(_mondayHold, _tuesdayHold и т.п.) хранятся временные промежуток (Пример: 02:00-03:00), разница в этом промежутке в один час. В функции DateClutch() происходит объединение промежутков, чтобы оптимизировать программный продукт и уменьшить количество записей

_monday, _tuesday и т.п. - это массив List(Созданы для более детального разбора ошибки), они изначально нечего в себе не содержат. Когда функция возвращает значения отличное от null, то программа выдает ошибку. Я пробовал задать двумя методами, но желаемого результата не добился:
- через знак "=";
- через функцию AddRange()

Выполняемый код:

```
if (_calendarUserTimeRADIOBUTTON.Checked)
{
    List<string> hold = new List<string>();
    /*
        _mondayHold Записываются данные (time)
     */
    // Cоединение времени
    _monday = GettingTheDayOfTheWeek(_mondayHold);
    // Cоединение времени
    _tuesday = GettingTheDayOfTheWeek(_tuesdayHold);
    // Cоединение времени
    _environs = GettingTheDayOfTheWeek(_environsHold);
    // Cоединение времени
    _thursday = GettingTheDayOfTheWeek(_thursdayHold);
    // Cоединение времени
    _friday = GettingTheDayOfTheWeek(_fridayHold);
    // Cоединение времени
    _saturday = GettingTheDayOfTheWeek(_saturdayHold);
    // Cоединение времени
    _sunday = GettingTheDayOfTheWeek(_sundayHold);

    hold.AddRange(_monday.ToArray());
    hold.AddRange(_tuesday.ToArray());
    hold.AddRange(_environs.ToArray());
    hold.AddRange(_thursday.ToArray());
    hold.AddRange(_friday.ToArray());
    hold.AddRange(_saturday.ToArray());
    hold.AddRange(_sunday.ToArray());
    NEWUSER.TimeWorkPc = 0;
}
else
{
    NEWUSER.TimeWorkPc = Convert.ToInt32(_hoursUserTEXTBOX.Text) / _hourInMinutes + Convert.ToInt32(_minuteUserTEXTBOX.Text);
}

int codeOperationCreateUser = SQL.CreateNewUser(NEWUSER.Login, NEWUSER.Password, NEWUSER.Name, NEWUSER.Patronymic,
        NEWUSER.TimeWorkPc, NEWUSER.URL, NEWUSER.Block, NEWUSER.Online, NEWUSER.HearingProblems,
        NEWUSER.RecordAudio, NEWUSER.RecordVideo, _calendarUserTimeRADIOBUTTON.Checked, NEWUSER.Access);

if (codeOperationCreateUser == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Пользователь создан");
}
else
{
    if (codeOperationCreateUser == 0) MessageBox.Show("При создании пользователя возникла ошибка!");
    else
    {
        Form1.ErrorConnect();
    }
}

private List<string> DateClutch(List<string> list)
{
    // Переменная в которую будут помещаться соединенное время
    List<string> hold = new List<string>();
    // Время, которое будет производить соединение
    string holdTime;
    // Удаление первого времени из массива
    int index;

    while (list.Count != 0)
    {
        index = 0;
        holdTime = list[index];
        //  Определение времени
        string hoursStart = holdTime[0].ToString() + holdTime[1].ToString();
        string hoursEnd = holdTime[6].ToString() + holdTime[7].ToString();
        list.RemoveAt(index);

        while (index < list.Count)
        {
            //  Запоминание рассматриваемого времени
            holdTime = list[index];

            if (hoursEnd == holdTime[0].ToString() + holdTime[1].ToString())
            {
                hold.Add(hoursStart + ":00-" + holdTime[6].ToString() + holdTime[7].ToString() + ":00");

                MessageBox.Show("Объект объединяется\n" + hoursStart + ":00-" + hoursEnd + ":00\nС\n"
                        + holdTime[0] + holdTime[1] + ":00-" + holdTime[6] + holdTime[7] + ":00\nПолученный ответ: " + hoursStart + ":00-" + holdTime[6].ToString() + holdTime[7].ToString() + ":00");

                list.RemoveAt(index);
                index--;
            }
            else
            if (hoursStart == holdTime[6].ToString() + holdTime[7].ToString())
            {
                hold.Add(holdTime[0].ToString() + holdTime[1].ToString() + ":00-" + hoursEnd + ":00");

                MessageBox.Show("Объект объединяется\n" + hoursStart + ":00-" + hoursEnd + ":00\nС\n"
                        + holdTime[0] + holdTime[1] + ":00-" + holdTime[6] + holdTime[7] + ":00\nПолученный ответ: " + holdTime[0].ToString() + holdTime[1].ToString() + ":00-" + hoursEnd + ":00");

                list.RemoveAt(index);
                index--;
            }
            index++;
        }
        //  Сделать дополнительную проверку на соединение времени
        if (hold.Count == 0) hold.Add(hoursStart + ":00-" + hoursEnd + ":00");
    }
    return hold;
}
```

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса. В приведенном коде нет ошибки. Кроме, конечно, показывания `MessageBox` в цикле.

Comment: А в каком месте хоть вылетает? Такая ошибка свойственна, если выполняется цикл foreach или используется enumerator в явном виде.

Comment: К примеру, массив "_sundayHold" имеет записи, а массивы "_mondayHold", "_tuesdayHold", "_environsHold", "_thursdayHold", "_fridayHold", "_saturdayHold" - пустые. Тогда программа выдаст данную ошибку в этой строке "_sunday = GettingTheDayOfTheWeek(_sundayHold);" - когда происходит присваивание массиву "_sunday ". Функций GettingTheDayOfTheWeek() работает исправно, корректная работа была проверена через MessageBox и дополнительного цикла, но его не включал в этот код, чтобы случайно не ввести в заблуждение других людей.

Comment: Давайте, я перефразирую, чтобы всем было понятнее. "Ошибка происходит в функции `GettingTheDayOfTheWeek`, но я вам ее не покажу, чтобы вас не смущать. Как мне исправить ошибку?" Вы попали в правильное место. Здесь такие вопросы задают постоянно.

Comment: Большое спасибо, когда копировал код данной функции, то на глаз попалась ошибка, теперь программа работает исправно. Всем спасибо за ваши комментарии.